# Why is my response not being cached?

Tags: http, cache-control

I am using express to write a response. 
My code is:

```
 res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300');
 res.send(data);
```

The headers I see are:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/some/path
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Request Headersview source

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:express:sess=eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1MzgxYTdjMDA0ZmIwMmIxMGI1NTdlZTMifQ==; express:sess.sig=lm-kq5ludtkWdRcFcVxNBL0BdT0
Host:localhost:9000
If-None-Match:W/"v9r1H7w4HiaXvycJ9FJ7lg=="
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36

Response Headersview source

access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type, X-API-KEY
access-control-allow-methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:public, max-age=300
connection:close
date:Sat, 03 Jan 2015 08:47:29 GMT
expires:Sat, 03 Jan 2015 08:52:29 GMT
etag:W/"v9r1H7w4HiaXvycJ9FJ7lg=="
x-powered-by:Express
```

However, I see my backend gets the request each and every time.

I have tried it with developers area open and closed and with "cache" on and off. 
Nothing seems to actually cache the request

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 304 Not modified means that your browser sent a message to check if its changed and the server said no. Are you wanting the behavior to be that the browser assumes no change?

Comment: @Aron I can't figure out why my backend still processes the request.

Comment: So the backend knows if the output changed

Comment: @Aron - I think I am getting where you're going. I am missing expires header, right? I added now (let me update the question), but I still see the request being processed by the backend

Comment: If your request contains this header `Cache-Control: max-age=0` each time, then your request is explicitly asking to **not** be served any cached data older than 0 seconds.  Could this explain why your backend gets the request for _e.g._ fresh data each time?